# Python print skip arguments

Tags: python, parameters

I have this dirty short line of code printing a formatted date:

```
print '%f %d' % math.modf(time.time())
```

Now the modf method gives back two arguments, so the print function expects both. In the sake of purely doing this, and not the simple alternative of putting the output separately in a variable; is there any existing way of excepting parameters in print or is there any way to call specific argument-indexes?

For example I have 3 arguments in a print:

```
print '%s %d.%f' % 'Money',19,.99
```

I want to skip the first String-parameter that is parsed. Is there any way to do this?

This is mainly a want-to-know-if-possible question, no need to give alternative solutions :P.

Comment: What do you want to do when skipping it?  In your second example, what do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in "old school" string formatting.

But the `format` method of strings does have this ability.

```
print "{1}".format ("1","2")
```

The above will skip the "1" and will only print "2".

I hope you don't mind I gave an alternative despite you not asking for it :)

Comment: It's still in my mindset ^^. I'm trying to see the possibilities of single-line outputting with a range of variables, yet skipping some. Weird thing is; I try this "print "{1} {2}".format (math.modf(time.time()))", yet it does not seem to understand the output of the modf method. I checked the python docs for the output type, but can't find it :(

Comment: Tested with raw print, it seems like a tuple: (0.46031999588012695, 1356216864.0), yet removing the surrounding parentheses it throws an syntax error..

Comment: @Allendar, what Jonas said, tuple unpacking ftw :)

Comment: lol I was so focused on the tuple part I didn't even notice the space was breaking the connection of the function and the parentheses :P. This works great, thank you ^^: print "{0} {1}".format(*math.modf(time.time()))

Comment: One more short addition :P; could you in this situation still declare (they're both FLOAT-type variables) that one has to be a digit (%d)? ^^

Comment: @Allendar, of course you can, [here's](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) the spec :)

Comment: Magnificent! Totally love this ^^. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bummer: The precision is not allowed for integer values. Touché lol. Guess if this expands even more I can just as well chain functions regex replacing the returned data :P